# htacces phpbb to xenforo

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, phpbb, xenforo

i am trying to redirect thoses urls ( from a phphbb )

```
http://www.example.com/fraiseuses/restauration-gambin-10n-t33924-45.html
http://www.example.com/fraiseuses/une-gambin-10n-plus-sur-forum-t34642.html#p675680
```

to a the correct xenforo url

```
http://www.example.com/threads/restauration-gambin-10n.33924/page-3
http://www.example.com/threads/34642/page-1#post-675680
```

my htacces

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+).html$ /posts/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*-f([0-9]+)$ /forums/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/topic([0-9]+).html /threads/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*-t([0-9]+).html /threads/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^\./]+-t([0-9]+)-15\.html$ /threads/$1/page-1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^\./]+-t([0-9]+)-30\.html$ /threads/$1/page-2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^\./]+-t([0-9]+)-45\.html$ /threads/$1/page-3 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately i can't find my mistake, can somebody point out my mistake please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no phpBB-specific redirect scripts, but these will work::

http://xenforo.com/community/threads/redirection-scripts-for-vbulletin-3-x.5030/

The basic function of these scripts is to map the old ids to the new ones. They can work with phpBB URLs given appropriate rewrite rules. Here are steps for you:

1) Upload these redirect scripts to your old forum location (the /forum folder):

http://xenforo.com/community/threads/redirection-scripts-for-vbulletin-3-x.5030/

You only need the 301config.php file and the showthread.php file to redirect threads (which are the most important thing).

2) Edit the 301config.php file. Uncomment this line (remove the //) and specify the path to your XF directory:

```
//  $fileDir = '/home/username/www/forums';
```

You may also need to specify the name of the import log table if it's not the default (xf_import_log). It may be named archived_import_log:

```
//  define('IMPORT_LOG_TABLE', 'import_log_x');
```

3) Add these rewrite rules to your .htaccess file in the /forum directory. This is based on previous phpBB imports. I assume your URLs follow the same format:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /forum/showthread.php?t=%2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

thx

i did this :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /threads/%2? [L,R=301,NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /posts/%2? [L,R=301,NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} f=(\d+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /forums/%1 [L,R=301,NC]
    RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /forums/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```